# Configuring subdomain MX records

Tags: email, mx-record, google-domains

I moved my domain to Google (not using GSuite). I use it only for private mails. I added an alias `me@mydomain.com` and it works as expected. But I wanted to create another one `me@info.mydomain.com`. Google doesn't support adding it from UI like regular aliases/forwardings, so I decided to configure it myself.

I have added `MX` records as described [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-add-new-mx-records), waited over 48h and when I try to send an email it says that there is no such email address.

I have also tried setting `CNAME` instead of `MX`, but it didn't work as well.

Here is my configuration:

[image: My configuration]

Comment: *"I have added MX records as described here, waited over 48h and when I try to send an email it says that there is no such email address."*  - The MX record only governs the routing of incoming mail to a specific set of mail servers. The other side of the equation is that those mail servers need to be configured and aware of what to do with messages addressed  your new (sub-) domain. - In other words you need to configure your google account to (also) accept e-mail for that additional `info` (sub-) domain.

Comment: Sounds legit, but still not sure how to do this. When Im adding an alias, I don't see my subdomain - I only can define the name before `@mydomain.com`, but I cannot change domain to subdomain - it is kinda hardcoded

Comment: I think that you'll need to add / associate the subdomain the same way you added your original custom domain (if having multiple domains is actually supported). But AFAIK nowadays custom domains is mostly if not exclusively a paid-for option that is part of  Google Workspace. So I can't help you with that part.

Comment: https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379?hl=en